# question on displacement and sculpt

Tags: sculpting, displacement

hi so what i did as in this tutorial was to add a displacement modifier to have a slightly uneven surface and then go to the sculpt mode to add details.

first thing is that after I supplied the displacement modifier it seems still have some kind of pixel like look...those squares... instead in the tutorial it looks so smooth..(i did supply the subdivision(2 as in the tutorial) before the displacement.

second question is mine seems part of those lines are under the surface so that I couldn't sculpt wherever i'd like to which doesn't seem like a problem in the tutorial.

ps the tutorial here
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ywSq0bSYLWI

my file
[image]

thank you for your time!!

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The way to solve your specific issue in this question is to set your model to *Shade Smooth*.

If you select it in object mode and right click it should be right there near the top.

[image]

However, pretty much everything about this tutorial is outdated from a sculpting perspective. Dyntopo is magnitudes slower than remesh or multires workflows, the main developer of the sculpt tools has said that you should only have Dynamic Topoplogy turned on for the exact amount of time you need it while trying to extrude new geo in sculpt mode, and basically disregard it as a tool for everything else. I would at least try to find a tutorial about sculpting from Blender post 2.8. Anything else is learning how to do stuff that you shouldn't be doing.